# BWT realisation using lists c#

Tags: c#

I'm tryin to realize bwt by reading file bytes (byte array instead strings), but I got a problems with memory using:

```
        List<List<byte>> shifts = new List<List<byte>>();
        List<byte> shift = new List<byte>();
        shift.AddRange(content);


        int shiftby = 0;
        while (shiftby < content.Count)
        {
            for (int i = content.Count - shiftby; i < content.Count; i++)
                shift.Add(content[i]);

            for (int i = 0; i < content.Count - shiftby; i++)
            {
                shift.Add(content[i]);
            }

            List<byte> clone = new List<byte>();
            //shift.ForEach((item) => clone.Add(item));
            clone.AddRange(shift);
            shifts.Add(clone);
            shift.Clear();
            shiftby++;
        }
```

it's works ok on small size - files (1-20Kb) but when it comes to 500 (or near) my pc just goes frozen and all 8gb operative is used, I know what's all because using "clone"-list, but else it's just keeps link in memory to "shift" list, and when I change "shift" - I change everything I keep'd in "shifts". So I need your suggestions and advices, 
p.s. and sorry for my english
p.s.s here you can see cyclic shift alhorithm (like you have string 123, and it will keep next strings in "shifts" { {123}, {312}, {231} }

Answer (score 1):

That's not surprising because you'd actually have quadratically more data than is in the file - the entire file duplicated (and shifted) for every byte in the file.

You don't need this for a [Burrows–Wheeler transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows%E2%80%93Wheeler_transform). You can represent every rotation with the index it starts at, keeping the original file and something that only "weighs" 4 times as much (one int for every byte in the file) for a total of 5 bytes per byte in the file (for almost every file, that's much smaller than a duplicate of the file).

That can be build faster than creating the indices and sorting them naively, using a suffix array.